# in operator comparison doesnt return expected result

Tags: javascript

```
let a=[1,2,3,4];
let m=[1,4,9,16];
for (let x in a) {
    x = parseInt(x)+1;
    console.log((x**2) in m)
}
```

I have tried it and every time I a getting output as `true`, `false`, `false`, `false`. Why so?
I am expecting it to return `true` in every case.

Comment: do you like to calculate with the index or with the value? the later `in` checks if a key exists in an object, not a value. btw, a value, which is already a number need no parsing.

Comment: I have to calculate it with the index only, it's a snippet of a project.

Comment: what are you trying to archieve? to check a value or an index?

Comment: Try `console.log(m.includes(x ** 2))` not `in`. `in` on array will check index not values so only 1 exist.

Comment: Done. Thanks @NenadVracar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the value with [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for a key. Then check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let m = [1, 4, 9, 16];

for (let x of a) { 
    console.log(m.includes(x ** 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding  `+1` for each element in array `a`.. use `includes` and not `in` for matching an `element` entry in another `array(say m, as per your snippet)`.

use debugger and run the snippet again

```
debugger;
    let a=[1,2,3,4];
    let m=[1,4,9,16];
    for (let x of a) {
        x = parseInt(x)+1; // you are increasing value by +1 here so [1,2,3,4] becomes [2,3,4,5]
        console.log(m.includes(x**2))  //prints true true true false
    }
```

So the last element is `5` times `5`, so it prints false on console.

Comment: adding debugger; will stop the code in browser and you need to click on "step over" in chrome so you can check values on each line..